# Ruby String: how to match a Regexp from a defined position

Tags: ruby, regex, string, slice

I want to match a regexp from a ruby string only from a defined position. Matches before that position do not interest me. Moreover, I'd like `\A` to match this position.

I found this solution:

```
code[index..-1][/\A[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/]
```

This match the regexp at position `index` in the string `code`. If the match is not exactly at position `index`, it return `nil`.

Is there a more elegant way to do this (I want to avoid to create the temporary string with the first slice)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `^.{#{index}}` inside the regular expression. Don't know if that's what you want, because I don't understand your question completely. Can you maybe add an example with the tested String? And have you heard of [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)? Great way to test your regular expressions.

This is how you could do it if I understand your question correctly:

```
code.match(/^.{#{index}}your_regex_here/)
```

The `index` variable will be put inside your regular expression. When `index = 4`, it will check if there's 4 characters from the beginning. Then it will check your own regular expression and only return true if yours is valid as well. I hope it helps. Good luck.

**EDIT**

And if you want to get the matched value for your regular expression:

```
code.scan(/^.{#{index}}([a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/).join
```

It puts the matched result (inside the brackets) in an Array and joins it into a String.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that `your_regex_here` cannot use `\A` or `^`. Reasonable solution if Mildred doesn't need to anchor anything at the beginning (or if they can modify their regex appropriately) though.