# Ruby Regexp#match to match start of string with given position (Python re-like)

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for a way to match strings from first symbol, but considering the offset I give to match method.

```
test_string = 'abc def qwe'
def_pos = 4
qwe_pos = 8

/qwe/.match(test_string, def_pos) # => #<MatchData "qwe">
# ^^^ this is bad, as it just skipped over the 'def'

/^qwe/.match(test_string, def_pos) # => nil
# ^^^ looks ok...

/^qwe/.match(test_string, qwe_pos) # => nil
# ^^^ it's bad, as it never matches 'qwe' now
```

what I'm looking for is:

```
/...qwe/.match(test_string, def_pos) # => nil
/...qwe/.match(test_string, qwe_pos) # => #<MatchData "qwe">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a string slice?

```
/^qwe/.match(test_string[def_pos..-1])
```

The `pos` parameter tells the regex engine where to start the match, but it doesn't change the behaviour of the start-of-line (and other) anchors. `^` still only matches at the start of a line (and `qwe_pos` is still in the middle of `test_string`).

Also, in Ruby, `\A` is the "start-of-string" anchor, `\z` is the "end-of-string" anchor. `^` and `$` match starts/ends of lines, too, and there is no option to change that behavior (which is special to Ruby, just like the charmingly confusing use of `(?m)` which does what `(?s)` does in other regex flavors)...

Comment: Yes, thanks. Got the same idea in similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292976/ruby-string-how-to-match-a-regexp-from-a-defined-position?rq=1. Now just need to figure the performance impact of this on BIG strings

Comment: Okay, doesn't seem to be a big performance hit and I won 1 more second in profiling :)

Comment: Thanks for \A addition. Already tripped on that figuring why the ^(\n+) group is matching on "< ...".

Comment: @Farcaller The perf impact on read-only string slices should be very small, the new string object will refer to the string storage area of the original string with appropriate new offset and length metadata.  It sets a _shared_ flag so appropriate copy on write semantics can be followed if there's subsequent mutation to the original or sliced string.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Wasn't sure that ruby strings are CoW.